# Browser not displaying JSON file - Setheader Nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, content-type

I'm trying to display a content on my browser as JSON file using the following code

```
const express = require ("express")
const app = express();

app.get("/test", async(req, res) => {
    const rows = await actiondb();
    res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    res.send(JSON.stringify(rows))
})
```

Even using the `setheader` and `"content-type", "application/json"` it is not working. The photo below shows the results

[image]

I was expecting to get something as:

[image]

What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser doesn't natively format JSON responses like you're showing in your example. If you want to format the JSON response in your browser, the browser extension [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en) can be installed into your browser. This will detect JSON/JSONP and display it for you formatted.

Example with the extension installed:

[image]

All this extension does is make the JSON response easier to read, it doesn't change the content type or data returned. Making a request to `/test` will work with or without the extension.

As a side-note, your code can be simplified to use express's [`.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) method:

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/test", async(req, res) => {
    const rows = await actiondb();
    res.json(rows);
});
```